# SQLALchemy query not returning column's values (sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.str' is not mapped)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to append SQLAlchemy's query result to a list.

My application contains following model ("**Game**)" and **games_query** (used as FlaskForm's QuerySelectField query_factory).
EDIT: Also added FlaskForm as it seems the problem has to do wi the form itself rather than query_factory.

```
class Game(db.Model):
   game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
   title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
   records = db.relationship('Record', backref='game')

def games_query():
   games_list = []
   for g in Game.query:
      games_list.append(g.title)
      print(g.title)
   return games_list

class ScoreForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[InputRequired()])
    score = IntegerField('Score', validators=[InputRequired()])
    game = QuerySelectField('Game', query_factory=games_query)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**games_query** returns the following error, despite printing g.title in the console returning valid values (games titles):

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.str' is not
> mapped

EDIT: Setting query_factory as a function returning basic lists results in the same error being displayed.

```
def games_query():
    games_list = ["Mario", "Zelda"]
    return games_list
```

How can I bypass that error sot hat **games_query** returns the list of the games titles that can be passed as options to relevant form's field?

Comment: Updated the initial post as I realised that the error has to do with the FlaskForm rather than the query_factory.

Answer (score 2):

I've found what caused the error. The solution is below.

The query_factory function shall only return complete query (not list, and not single column of the query):

```
def games_query():
    return db.session.query(Game)
```

Jinja code related to the FlaskForm by default will display primary_key column, unless will set a specific column in the FlaskForm by using get_label attribute:

```
class ScoreForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[InputRequired()])
    score = IntegerField('Score', validators=[InputRequired()])
    game = QuerySelectField('Game', query_factory=games_query, get_label='title')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def games_query():
   games_list = []
   for row in Game.query:
      games_list.append(row.__dict__['title'])
      print(row.__dict__['title'])
   return games_list
```

Try it

Comment: Thanks for help but with your solution I'm getting exactly same error message ("Class 'builtins.str' is not mapped").

Comment: Oh, I have the same code, but run well, check the model, and add the: __tablename__ = 'Game'.